# Visual Studio Nuget manager does not show OpenTK package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, opentk

I am trying to add OpenTK as a dependency. When I open the Nuget Package Manager, the only Package source displayed is "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages", so I went to `Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources` and added the package source:

- Name: nuget.org
- Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

I now get the following list of packages, but the OpenTK package is not there.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to installing packages that do not show up on the Nuget manager GUI, I can use the Package Manager Console which finds OpenTK without problem.

```bash
PM> Install-Package OpenTK
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, @Freddy J.  You can add an answer and accept your own answer https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/. This will help other users who has the same issue and someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem. Just a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the package you need:
[image]

You can check if your scroll wheel is on the top and if there is any package you missed